# Raising integers to high powers

Tags: c++

Please help me with the steps to solve this programming problem on SPOJ: [7683. Powered and Squared](http://www.spoj.com/SPOJ/problems/CSQUARE/).

The problem calls for raising integers to very high powers - up to 10^120. The power to which an integer is to be raised is expressed as a 250-digit number in base 3. A trivial algorithm times out, because the number of multiplications is insanely high. Is there a better approach?

Comment: Is this a homework? Also the answer is *fast exponentiation*.

Comment: no just for practice,please give stepwise solution cant figure out what to do

Comment: There are two problems with fast exponentiation also:

1.b can go upto 3^250 so computing a^b might be non sensical.
2.b is in base 3,conveting to base 10 would cost a lot I think

Comment: You will have to edit your question. First you need to explain what you did and even post your code. Then anyone will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The key to solving this problem is realization of the fact that "square" in "fast exponentiation by squares" is not a magic number: it could be cubes, or any power that you would like. This particular problem calls for exponentiation by cubes, though, because `b` is written in the base-3 notation.

It is relatively easy to extend the classic algorithm to work with cubes:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

typedef long long i64;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char buf[1024];
    fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
    int t = atoi(buf);
    while (t--) {
        fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
        char* b;
        i64 a = strtol(buf, &b, 10);
        // b points to the first space; find the second space
        b = strchr(++b, ' ');
        // This is where m begins
        i64 m = atoi(b--);
        a %= m;
        i64 res = 1;
        // We process b starting from the back
        while (*b != ' ') {
            if (*b == '1') {
                res *= a;
            } else if (*b == '2') {
                // The part that differs from the classic algorithm is here:
                res *= a*a;
            }
            res %= m;
            // We do exponentiation by cubes, hence it's a*a*a
            a = (a * a * a) % m;
            // End of the interesting part
            b--;
        }
        printf("%d\n", (int)res);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem in SPOJ is set in a way that makes C++ I/O prohibitively slow, so this whole annoying manipulation with character pointers is, unfortunately, necessary.